# Is there a way to use the stackexchange syntax for posts, commits comments, wiki... in redmine

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Is there a module or a simple way to enable the [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from stackexchange in redmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest version of redmine (2.2.2) I found that none of the plugins on the website worked.

I finally found a [fork of redmine_markdown_extra_formatter](https://github.com/urigon/redmine_markdown_extra_formatter) which works with the current version of redmine.

---

For reference I tried:

- [redmine_markdown_formatter](https://github.com/bitherder/redmine_markdown_formatter/tree)
- [redmine_markdown_extra_formatter](https://github.com/juno/redmine_markdown_extra_formatter/tree)
- [redmine_redcarpet_formatter](https://github.com/alminium/redmine_redcarpet_formatter)
- [chiliproject_markdown_formatter](https://github.com/Odie/chiliproject_markdown_formatter)
- [redmine_ultraviolet](https://github.com/epitron/redmine_ultraviolet)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a [Markdown formatter plugin](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_List#Markdown-formatter-plugin) for redmine.  It probably doesn't match SE's markdown flavour exactly, but it'll put you in the right direction.

Comment: This looks promising! I'll try this out on the next server maintenance. Thank you.